# How can I write the following nonlinear constraint optimization as nonlcon in fmincon?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I want to solve the following optimization problem with `fmincon` in MATLAB, but I can not define its non-linear constraint.
[image]

```
K=E(ρ(z)) , c=1 , T=5 , z=randn; r_t=ab(:,t);
```

My loss function `ρ` are the two criterion functions and `c` is a constant.
I have written a piece of code as follows.

```
x0=[0 0 0 0]';%'//
ab=[ 0.0181   -0.0041    0.0040    0.0373    0.0580    0.0009    0.0250   -0.0009    0.0205    0.0302 
    0.0290    0.0260    0.0260   -0.0234    0.0250   -0.0136   -0.0311   -0.0451    0.0576   -0.0288];

T=5;
z=randn;
f=@(x) ((1/6)*(1-(1-(x)^2)^3))*(abs(x)<=1)+(1/6)*(abs(x)>=1);
K=mean(f(z));

Aeq=[1 1 0 0];
beq=1;
fun=@(x) x(3);
x=fmincon(fun,x0,[],[],Aeq,beq,[],[],nonlcon);
```

Please help me if you can.

Comment: you did not define nonlcon

Comment: @pseudoDust that's exactly what his first paragraph says: `I can not define its non-linear constraint.`